# Wifi turns off on NookColor when put to sleep. How can I prevent this?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, wi-fi, nook-color

I have a rooted NookColor.  Everytime I put the device to sleep and then unlock the device on the next use, I have to disable the wifi and re-enable it in order to get wifi working again.  I've tried downloading the SpareParts app from the Android Market and setting the wifi sleep policy to "never" but it still loses the wifi during sleep.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue only happens when ad-hoc is enabled.  See here for more info: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=872521